# Почему id - пустое?

Tags: html, javascript

У меня есть такой див

```
<div id = "'+data2[i]["id"]+'" onclick = "deleteMessage()" style = "float:right;">
```

А функция deleteMessage() такая

```
function deleteMessage() {
    var item = $(this).parent();
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
    $.post('/profile/deleteMyWallMessage/', {
        'id': id
    }, function (data) {
        item.remove();
    });
}
```

Тут у меня в id пустое, почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onclick = "deleteMessage(this)"

function deleteMessage(obj) {
    //// А вот тут уже можешь его оборачивать в jQuery.... хотя как по мне - быдлокод :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Может передавать сразу в функцию?

```
onclick = "deleteMessage(data2[i]["id"])"  ?
```

Comment: так тоже пробовал не получается:(

Comment: function deleteMessage(id) {
    var item = $('Что за this? от куда он ?').parent();
    var id = id;
    console.log(id);
    $.post('/profile/deleteMyWallMessage/', {
        'id': id
    }, function (data) {
        item.remove();
    });
}

Comment: это потому что мой див внутри другово дива, вот так

Comment: $("#messages").prepend('<div>'+'<font color="red">'+data2[i]["user"]+' '+'</font><font color="blue">'+data2[i]["text"]+'</font>'+'<div id = "'+data2[i]["id"]+'" onclick = "deleteMessage()" style = "float:right;">'+'Delete'+'</div>'+'</div>');

Comment: дай нормальный id диву , и id статьи или что там, передавай в функцию

Comment: получилось спасибо :)
еще у меня есть котроллер profileController в котором есть функция deleteMyWallMessage()
{
include MODEL_DIR."/userModel.php";
            $userModel = new UserModel();
            $userModel->deleteMyWallMessage($_POST['id']);
}
a в моделе есть функция
public function deleteMyWallMessage($id)
        {
            $query = "DELETE * FROM wallmessages WHERE id = '".$id."'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
        }
но не удается удалять строку из базы, почему?

Comment: не понятный код, напиши на e-mail мне я отвечу

Comment: А все, DELETE * FROM wallmessages WHERE id = '".$id."'" на DELETE FROM wallmessages WHERE `id` = $id